# Giant Connector Plug

Tags: connector, high-current, plug, gauge, scart

I'm looking for a very big connector plug, similar to the old SCART connectors, except I need it to be at the following specs:

No Of Pins: At least 35, preferably 50
Gauge size: At least 12 pins with min 12AWG, at least another 10 with min 18 or 20AWG, and the rest whatever theyy come in. (If they only come in one size, then an entire thing of 12 AWG is fine
Amp Rating: The higher the better!

Does anyone have any idea as to a store or catalogue where I could find one? Or, if you know a specific one, that would also be great!

Also, Can anyone give me it's proper name? (Connector Plug? Multi-Pin Plug)

Thanks,

Sasha

Comment: Connector contacts are not specified like wire gauge, they're specified with rated current, voltage and frequency. So specify these parameters first.

Answer (score 2):

A mil standard size 40 shell with a 40-9 insert will give you 1 #8, 22 #12, and 26 #16 contacts, which would be a total of 47. Go to Digikey.com, look at product lines, and under circular connectors select shell size-insert 40-9. As of a few minutes ago, that will give you 84 choices.

The next size down with the necessary power contacts is the 36-18 insert, with 1 #4, 2 #8, 14 #12, and 14 #16, but this is only a total of 31.

Answer (score 1):

Check page 24 of this [catalog](http://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/pdf/12-026.pdf) for a 40-49 insert, which will give you most of what you want and all the information you'll need to order the mating connectors and any accessories you may need/want